# How can I run scantokens with modified environment, but use the normal environment within the scanned code?

Tags: catcodes

For example if I run

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


{% prepare a token list <a> (assume this is provided by user)
\catcode 13=12\relax  % 12:other
\global\def\a{line 1^^M^^Mline 2^^M^^Mnewlinechar=\the\newlinechar^^M}%
}

% scan \a, but with newlinechar=13...
\newlinechar=13\relax
\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\a}
% but then the code inside should still see newlinechar=10.

\end{document}
```

each part separated by the character with charcode 13 will be written as a separate line; however the code inside will see \newlinechar=13.

Assume I want the code inside to see the value to be equal to the normal value i.e. 10 instead. How can I achieve that? (the command doesn't seem to provide any obvious way to do it.)

(Also assume that the code inside is an arbitrary user-provided content that should probably not be touched, and it may contain catcode-changing command that should be obeyed.)

Comment: Side note, it would be better for the code to make less assumptions e.g. "character X has catcode Y in the current environment". I.e. I want to do the equivalent of inserting something (reset newlinechar) between the `\write` and the `\input` that the `scantokens` is equivalent to.

Comment: scantokens is only affected by catcodes and is more or less unrelated to `\newlinechar`  if you want the internal write done by scantokens to see newlinechar=10 just set that before the call (the default in latex anyway)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No but the point is that I want to reset it before the code inside is run?

Comment: i.e. \write with newlinechar=13, \input with newlinechar=10.

Comment: the fact that newlinechar has any effect at all here is just an unfortunate artifact of the way scanokens is implemented as an easy hook doing a write then a read  I'd never use it  this way if you want ^^J and ^^M to do something special in a scantokens make them active

Comment: So you're using `\scantokens` only to change your `\newlinechar`s? Why use it anyway, just replace the literal charcode13-catcode12 tokens with charcode10 tokens.

Comment: @Skillmon No, assume that it's general user-provided code *but* the new lines are represented by char 13.

Comment: Ah you mean replace in the tokenlist before passing to scantokens? Maybe that would work... (but then if the user *already* have char10 tokens -- unlikely though)

Comment: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nee } \tl_replace_all:Nee \a { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } } { \char_generate:nn { 10 } { 12 } } \tl_set_rescan:Nno \a {} { \a }` and you're done (though `\a` doesn't match naming conventions in `expl3`, and maybe you should use a `l3regex` function to also convert newlines inside of braced groups, or (since `\tl_set_rescan:Nno` does it anyway) convert your input into a string, do the replacement using `\str_replace_all:Nnn` and then use `\tl_set_rescan:Nno`, would give better performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, there are a few ways I can figure out.

### Modify the input to suit the newlinechar

As suggested by Skillmon.

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nee }
\tl_replace_all:Nee \a { \char_generate:nn { 13 } { 12 } } { \char_generate:nn { \newlinechar } { 12 } }
\tl_set_rescan:Nno \a {} { \a }
```

**Issue**: get into problems if `\newlinechar` is -1 or some other weird value e.g. `/`, and the user code happen to have a `/` as well.

### Expand `\scantokens` once then revert newlinechar

Looks like the o-expansion of `\scantokens` is similar to the o-expansion of `\@@input`, put the content in front of the input stream.

This will work for the example in the question. (before executing `\endgroup` expand the `\scantokens` once. The other one is to expand the `\a`.
Side note, `\scantokens` is a primitive that expand the following tokens until it sees a `{`, so another `\expandafter` before it isn't necessary.)

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


{% prepare a token list <a> (assume this is provided by user)
\catcode 13=12\relax  % 12:other
\global\def\a{line 1^^M^^Mline 2^^M^^Mnewlinechar=\the\newlinechar^^M}%
}

% scan \a, but with newlinechar=13...
\begingroup\newlinechar=13\relax\expandafter\endgroup
\scantokens\expandafter{\a}
% but then the code inside should still see newlinechar=10.

\end{document}
```

### Use an active character to revert newlinechar inside the rescanned tokens

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


{% prepare a token list <a> (assume this is provided by user)
\catcode 13=12\relax  % 12:other
\global\def\a{line 1^^M^^Mline 2^^M^^Mnewlinechar=\the\newlinechar^^M}%
}

\begingroup
\catcode `\~\active
\let~\endgroup
\newlinechar=13\relax
\scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter~\a}

\end{document}
```

I think this method doesn't have any disadvantage (if the default catcode of `~` is not active it will be reset when the group is closed, and `\endlinechar` doesn't matter). Basically

- open a group
- make `~` active, and make it close the group when executed
- set `\newlinechar`
- pass `~⟨content⟩` to `\scantokens`. When the rescanned `~` is executed the group will be closed.

Comment: Maybe in the special case the content inside is empty the last method would insert an extraneous endlinechar token... not sure?